# Rails 4: setup custom redirect_to in link_to helper with remote: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, link-to

In my Rails 4 app, I have a `calendar` and a `post` models: a `calendar` `has_many` `post`s and a `post` `belong_to` a `calendar`.

In `Calendars#Show`, I display all the `post`s that belong to this `calendar`.

In this very same view, I use the following link to `update` the `approval` custom attribute of a `post`:

```
<%= link_to post_path(:id => @post.id, "post[approval]" => "ok"), :method => :patch %>
```

Problem, once I click this link, I am taken to the `Posts#Show` view of this post.

What I would like instead, is to remain on the same `Calendars#Show` view.

I thought of implementing a `redirect_to :back` in my `Posts#Update` action in the controller, but this is not possible, since this would redirect me to the `Posts#Edit` view when I update a post from this very same `Posts#Edit` view.

So, I am looking for a solution to implement a redirect_to specifically for my `link_to` helper with `remote: true` from the `Calendars#Show` to the `Calendars#Show`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> with `remote: true`

If you're using `remote` (your code snippet does **not** have it), you *won't* be redirected anyway:

```
<%= link_to post_path(:id => @post.id, "post[approval]" => "ok"), :method => :patch, remote :true %>
```

The `remote: true` functionality invokes [*ajax*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)), which is an XML call (through JS) to your server. By virtue of the call being out of "scope" (IE not a standard "request"), it will not cause any changes to your current browser state, *unless* you trigger them yourself:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def update
      @post = Post.find params[:id]
      respond_to do |format|
         if @post.update
           format.json #-> fired only when json is datatype
           format.js #-> invokes app/views/posts/update.js.erb
           format.html { redirect_to @post } #-> only fires on http request
         end
      end
   end
end

#app/views/posts/update.js.erb
## do what you want here
```

> from the `Calendars#Show` to the `Calendars#Show`

If you want to refresh your page, you could use:

```
#app/views/posts/update.js.erb
window.location.reload(true);
```

--

To give you some more context, *ajax* stands for **a**synrhconous **j**avascript **a**nd **x**ml. This means that each of the requests you send with it are considered to be [*asynchronous*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_communication) -- or out of scope of the "normal" HTTP request.

[image]

Ajax requests are *meant* to be used to apply changes / updates to an already loaded page. A good example would be a *chat* system or something.

Your question of how to *redirect* after an Ajax response, although not wrong, is definitely against convention of how it's considered to work. If you wanted to create a redirect as you are attempting to, I would highly recommend using a standard HTTP request with some conditions in your action:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def update
       @post = Post.find params[:id]
       @post.update post_params
       redirect_to posts_path if @post.approved.changed?
       redirect_to root_path if ....
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your accurate and complete answer, much appreciated. You are right, I am kind of missing the point when I want to redirect after an AJAX response. What I am really trying to do is to update a specific section of my page, once the link is clicked, and based on the new value the click placed in the database. So, I guess I am going to need to work with this `update.js.erb` file.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an AJAX request, in your Post controller you need to respond to js:

```
def update
  # ...
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.update(post_params)
      format.js { head :ok } # see here no redirects
      # ... other formats
    else
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```